# SocketException: Invalid argument

Tags: netty

I've wrote transport server based on netty 4.0.32.Final

In very seldom situations I get the next error on Oracle Solaris 11.1 SPARC:

```
Failed to set a channel option: [id: 0x970c09c4, /91.221.145.225:48986 => /0.0.0.0:0]
io.netty.channel.ChannelException: java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument
at io.netty.channel.socket.DefaultSocketChannelConfig.setReuseAddress(DefaultSocketChannelConfig.java:222)
at io.netty.channel.socket.DefaultSocketChannelConfig.setOption(DefaultSocketChannelConfig.java:113)
at io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap$ServerBootstrapAcceptor.channelRead(ServerBootstrap.java:239)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioMessageChannel$NioMessageUnsafe.read(AbstractNioMessageChannel.java:93)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument
at sun.nio.ch.Net.setIntOption0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.setSocketOption(Net.java:356)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.setOption(SocketChannelImpl.java:190)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.setBooleanOption(SocketAdaptor.java:271)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.setReuseAddress(SocketAdaptor.java:389)
at io.netty.channel.socket.DefaultSocketChannelConfig.setReuseAddress(DefaultSocketChannelConfig.java:220)
... 12 more
```

Here are the options [SO_REUSEADDR=true, TCP_NODELAY=true, SO_LINGER=-1, WRITE_BUFFER_LOW_WATER_MARK=10240, WRITE_BUFFER_HIGH_WATER_MARK=20480, MESSAGE_SIZE_ESTIMATOR=io.netty.channel.DefaultMessageSizeEstimator@350c136d]

I've investigated that the native call of sun.nio.ch.Net.setIntOption0(Native Method) after all will lead to setsockopt invocation.

In documentation listed here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26505_01/html/816-5170/getsockopt-3socket.html
is written that:

EINVAL
The specified option is invalid at the specified socket level, or the socket has been shut down.

So, possibly "Invalid argument" error is raised because the socket was closed at the moment when my application tried to set socket options...

Is my investigation correct?
And if yes, is it possible somehow to detect in netty code such situation in order to prevent such error and not to call option set?